# FTP acknowledge transfer completion

Tags: java, file, ftp, file-transfer, data-transfer

I am transferring files at regular intervals to remote system via FTP using a Java client. The files are huge in size(>10MB). A third-party application processes these files in remote path. Now the problem is that file is being created at remote path and while the transfer is still in progress the third-party application starts processing it. I need to avoid this.

Solution suggested by third-party side was to have another file transferred containing size in bytes. Suppose file being transferred is *Transaction_20160513_1130.csv* then after completion transfer another file *Transaction_20160513_1130.size* which will be a plain text containing size in bytes of *Transaction_20160513_1130.csv*

Is there a better solution than the above? This might be a common issue. Hope there is a common solution as well.

Comment: `Stats` file is also a common solution which your third party suggested

Comment: Transferring another file / stats file looks like a overhead. Thinking of some solution like renaming file after transfer or setting some file attribute after completion

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your FTP server allows renaming files a simpler solution would be to do the upload with filename like `Transaction_20160513_1130.temp` and after the upload ends do a rename to `Transaction_20160513_1130.csv` and in the remote system only process files with the correct extension.